# MySQL update query on a single table with value from joined table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables named :

```
url_alias
product
```

`url_alias` TABLE has following fields : `id`, `query`, `keyword`

`id` is numeric,

`query` is of the form `"product_id=45"`

`keyword` is of the form `"product-actual-name-in-url-friendly-manner"`

`product` table has following fields: `product_id`, `name`, `language_id`

What I want is to update `url_alias` table `"keyword"` field with proper url friendly string which I have generated by using mysql REPLACE function and is aliased as NEW_KEYWORD but the url friendly string needs to be auto-generated from a join of both tables .

Following query shows a `SELECT` query on tables properly:

```
SELECT u.url_alias_id, u.query, u.keyword, p.name, REPLACE( p.name, ' ', '-' ) AS NEW_KEYWORD
FROM url_alias u, product p
WHERE u.query = CONCAT( "product_id=", p.product_id )
AND p.language_id =3
```

Please help me in an update query by using this query

Comment: what output you want in keyword field.

Comment: I want the "keyword" field to contain the NEW_KEYWORD alias value which I've generated using the mysql REPLACE function. 

The problem is that the keyword field currently contains the url friendly name of product in English language which is language ID 1 but now I wish it to contain the url friendly name of product in another language say German which has language ID 3

Comment: You have a cross join there, are you sure you get not too many results (and especially the right one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
UPDATE url_alias u 
JOIN product p 
ON u.query = CONCAT( "product_id=", p.product_id ) 
SET u.keyword=REPLACE( p.name, ' ', '-' ) 
WHERE p.language_id =3;
```